# coldfusion 11 spooler & cfmail threading

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, cfmail

Current scenario:
Using cfmail tag with query  for example.

```
<cfmail   
    query="qName"   
    to="#tomailvar#" 
    from="#frommailvar#>"
    subject="#subjectvar#"  
    type="html" 
    server="smtp.sendgrid.net" 
    timeout="360"  
    username="#myuservar#"  
    password="#mypwdvar#"  
>
```

how can i do threading in cfmail tag  or current code?

I have client they send almost 40k in one shoot some time more.
I gave multiple accounts to my client, some time they simultaneous two users or three users sends 40k + 40k+  emails.

Is there a way i can count messages in spooler folder and verify with my total count of query ?

> what is the right way to handle  this much emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of ColdFusion are you using?  I'm surprised that you aren't encountering timeout issues.  Since ColdFusion 6, we've been saving the HTML, TEXT and email list to a separate database and then have a background task loop over the data and send it in smaller batches.

Have you considered using a Transactional Email Service?  We recently switched from Mandrill (because they're rolling it into MailChimp) to SparkPost (Free tier = 100,000 messages/mo). This type of service would provide you with the best stats & bounce/read/click detection (and sending 40k messages would take about ~2 seconds using CFHTTP.)  You could also incorporate using "tags" for your accounts that are sending so you can keep track or set up separate accounts for each client.  (NOTE: If you use SMTP API, be sure to set up unique DNS CNAMES for each SMTP customer or ColdFusion may use an existing authenticated connection and send messages using the wrong SMTP account.)

In addition to SMTP connections (one message at time), REST APIs are available which allow you to generate & post a single JSON packet containing the HTML/TEXT templates, email list, substitution parameters, campaign id, tags, optional headers, etc. I prefer sending through these services because it doesn't result in my IPs being blacklisted or incur delivery delays of time-sensitive messages.

Here's a comparison chart of various transactional email providers.

http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/transactional-emailing-providers-mailjet-sendgrid-critsend

Here's a sample REST API call using [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/). (I'm providing this because almost no third-party services provide code samples for CFML.)

```
<cfscript>
APIKey = "abc123";
/* Generate Message Object */
messageObject = {
    "campaign_id" = "Test1234",
    "options" = {
        "open_tracking" = Javacast("boolean", true),
        "click_tracking" = Javacast("boolean", true)
    },
    "recipients" = [
        {"address" = {"email" = "user1@email.com", "name"="User 1 Name"}, "substitution_data"= {"fullname"="Mr. User 1"}},
        {"address" = {"email" = "user2@email.com", "name"="User 2 Name"}, "substitution_data"= {"fullname"="Ms. User 2"}},
    ],
    "content" = {
        "tags" = ["testing", "demo"],
        "from" = {"email"="my@email.com", "name"="My Name"},
        "subject" = "Oh hey {{fullname}} (#Request.DateTimeFormat(StartTime,'m/d/yyyy')#)",
        "html" = "<b>Testing REST API {{fullname}}</b><br><br>Sending email using a transactional email service.",
        "text" = "Testing REST API {{fullname}} - Sending email using a transactional email service.",
        "headers" = {
            "X-CUSTOM-HEADER" = "foo bar"
        }
    }
};
/* Recommend using JSONUtil for proper casting of boolean values */
JSONUtil = CreateObject("component","JSONUtil");
MessageJSON = JSONUtil.Serialize(var=messageObject, strictMapping=true);
</cfscript>

<cfhttp url="https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmission" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60" getasbinary="never">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#APIKey#">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#MessageJSON#">
</cfhttp>

<CFDUMP VAR="#httpResp#">
```

Comment: so your saying if im using API in my case im using sendgrid its ok to send 40k in one shoot ?

Comment: Using SendGrid's "mail.send" endpoint, they only allow "up to 10,000 recipients per API request".  You'd have to perform 4+ posts in order to send a single email job.  They also require recipient addresses to be posted in individual form fields (ugh, 10,000+ form fields?) https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html It doesn't appear that they allow substitution parameters either (ie, hello {name}).

Comment: Check out SparkPost.  They currently charge $199 for 1 million emails/mo.  SendGrid charges $399 for 700,000 (and you need to contact them for rates if you go over 700k.)  You're paying a lot more for less and I think you'll like the SparkPost APIs alot better.

Comment: great thanks .....let me have a look sparkpost... is there a way we can check spooler count?

Comment: Good luck with that. Spooled messages will occasionally, according to our tests & SMTP server logs, never make any connection to be sent, move to the "Undelivr" folder and still be listed in the "mail.log" file as "sent".  You could loop over all of the email addresses (& campaign) and log it to a database (or using CFLog.) We've been saving the mailer ID & list of email addresses used during the send. (Since using SparkPost, we're logging the entire JSON packet as the "send receipt". It makes it extremely easy to re-send.)

Comment: Spooler count? Use CFDirectory to count the ".cfmail" files. It can be very slow if there are many files.  Make sure you use (type="file" listinfo="name") to return minimal info.   I discovered using the command line is significantly faster (1.2 seconds versus 18).  http://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/134494777569/cfexecute-dir-is-faster-than-cfdirectory

Comment: sorry just trying to understand... is sendgrid save messages in spooler fold as i showed you my sample code?

Comment: No. You are using SendGrid's SMTP API.  This process is dependent upon CFmail successfully spooling & making a connection per message. There's no way to count temporary spooled files as some messages are sent immediately (and some may not send at all even though CF will log that they were sent.) SendGrid's "mail.send" API requires a CFHTTP form post and can accept 10,000 recipients per post. If your messages aren't personalized, I would recommend checking their "Web API".